# Android NDK get object from Java

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to know how to get a custom object from Java to c++?

I need to implement a method in c++ for get performance. I already have the method working in java but I want to port to c++.

On Java a I call the method like this:

```
private native boolean P(Mat Previous, String Name);
```

On CPP file I need to get the mat object. Getting string is easy! But how can I get the custom mat object similar to c++(cv::Mat)? I need to get java Mat into a cv::Mat.
Here the cpp file:

```
JNIEXPORT bool JNICALL Java_br_raphael_detector_SimpsonDetector_P
                      (JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz, jobject Previous, jstring Name){
jboolean sim = false;

const char* N = env->GetStringUTFChars(Name,0);
std::string Nome = N;


//Release
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(Name,N);

//Then Return
return sim;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

A java `Mat` object is **a totally different thing** from a native `cv::Mat`, you can't get one directly from the other.

That said, if you know what fields are inside `Mat`, and you know the corresponding fields in `cv::Mat`, you can write a conversion function that copies the contents of the fields one-by-one.

```
// First get the Mat class
jclass Mat = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, Previous);

// To get a field
jfieldId field = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, Mat, "fieldName", field type);

// To get a method
jmethodId method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, Mat, "methodName", method signature);
```

from there you can read the values of fields, or call methods

```
// getting a field
(*env)->GetObjectField(env, Previous, field);

// calling a method
(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, Previous, method, parameters);
```

refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html for details

Answer (score 0):

I'm one year late to the party, but the way you pass a Mat to C is with a jlong with the address of the Java's Mat. You can do something like this:

```
private static native boolean P(long matAddress, String name);
```

In C:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_br_raphael_detector_SimpsonDetector_P
                  (JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz, jlong matAddress, jstring Name)
{  
    cv::Mat* image = (cv::Mat*)matAddress;
    // Do stuff with image.
}
```

Then you would call the method in Java like this:

```
P(myMat.getNativeObjAddr(), name);
```

OpenCV exposes this method just for cases like this. (I would link to the documentation's page but the website is not loading here, sorry.)